# Is imputing median for NAs in a dataset the best approach. If yes/no, so why?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to carry out some data cleaning. My data includes survey questions answered by respondents on a scale of 1 to 5(factor type data). I had a few NAs in my dataset. I have 49 variables. Now i want to impute the NAs in each column with the median of that column.

I tried to convert data to numeric to be able to get medians & after that i tried to convert list to dataframe but it didn't work.

```
# Replacing NAs with median
# data.class(data3$column)
data4 <- lapply(data3,as.numeric)
median(data4$ER_ALLVIS)

# Replacing NAs with median
data5 %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE), .))
```

i want to impute the NAs in each column with the median of that column.

Comment: Impute with the median is not a clever idea, IMO you should consult a statistician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While imputing using the mean or median is not the best approach by any stretch of the imagination, in practice it is very common. If this is the approach you wish to take:

```
data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), median(as.numeric(as.character(x)))))
```

Comment: Thnx a lot for the help Dij. Can you please tell me if this code will change the median of each column individually based on that column's median OR it will take median of whole dataset & impute a common median number in all NAs ?

Comment: Also it would be great if you can share other better ways of imputation, thanks again

Comment: Another thing is - Now i treid to convert my output variable to binary scale by putting 1,2,3,4 as 0 & 5 as 1 but i am getting following error -                      Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, data5$ER_VEH == 1, value = c(5L, 5L, 6L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated                                                                                    Can you please tell how can i resolve this. I tried using as.dataframe but it didnt work?

Comment: @RaghuNandan this code will compute a median for each feature (i.e., each column) separately. If you want to use the median for the dataset, that is a lot easier.

Comment: @RaghuNandan I'm not sure what code you're using to convert the factor to binary so I'm not sure exactly what is causing your error to arise. Though, if you wish to operate on levels of a factor that are represented by numbers, I suggest converting it to numeric: `data5$ER_VEH <- as.numeric(as.character(data5$ER_VEH))`. Then you can replace values using `<`, `>`, or `=` operators. `ifelse(data5$EV_VEH < 5, 0, 1)`

Comment: @RaghuNandan Other preferred methods of imputation include `bayesian PCA imputation` and `KNN imputation`, but this is beyond the scope of your question. Good luck!

Comment: @Dij Thanks a lot again, you have been a great help.

Comment: or read appropriate bits of Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* book, or check out the `mice` package